# More information about worldwide nodes how to get?

Tags: tracking, web-hosting, networking

The context:

Six hosts across worldwide were traced over week from UK. Ten thousands of lines to be parsed and analysed.

And then I try to find any clue of geographical information and path - from where it jumps where.

Then after Austria or Germany(each time different) I have mysterious 62.208.72.6 which in GEO LOC gives me Falklands Islands (which is where my target host is by the way, but before target host I still have 5 other nodes)

Then I do whois for this  62.208.72.6

route:        62.208.0.0/16

descr:        DE-ECRC-62-208-0-0

origin:       AS1273

mnt-by:       CW-EUROPE-GSOC

source:       RIPE # Filtered

Why it says Europe now? How to understand this enigma code? I want to confirm more or less whether this is in europe or in falkland islands? But it can't be in FK yet as after next two hosts I get New York?

Could you also tell me what does this CW-EUROPE-GSOC abbreviation means. (To preserve your sanity better not google, unless you already know it :-D)

And the actual whois for the destination/target host, which completely destroys my head:

route:        195.248.193.0/24

descr:        HORIZON

descr:        Cable and Wireless Falkland Islands

descr:        Via Cable and Wireless Communications UK

origin:       AS5551

mnt-by:       AS5551-MNT

source:       RIPE # Filtered

How is it Via Cable and Wireless Communications UK if two nodes before I was in New York?

Thank you guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular places to trace an IP and see who owns it are

https://www.arin.net/

http://www.ripe.net/

http://www.apnic.net/

For a complete list of routing registries around the world who maintain IP records visit

http://www.irr.net/docs/list.html

People can use tor network to connect to you from various nodes around the world one connection they can be in Europe, the next Asia, the USA or any other place for that matter. I'm not sure what you are asking but use the services above to determine who owns an IP.

`CW-EUROPE-GSOC` is

```
Cable and Wireless plc
address:        Melbourne Street
address:        Leeds
address:        LS2 7PS
address:        United Kingdom
phone:          +44 1344 602224
e-mail:         noc@eu.cw.net
```